# Add hyperlink to inside a existing PDF file in written text

Tags: pdf, text, hyperlink, addition

So, I want to hyperlink a text present in a PDF using Python.

Its a architect diagram from CIVIL construction in that diagram there are some text thos defind name of the diagram.
In that text i want to add hyperlink

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have code to show how you expect python can do it for an unknown rect num or dest? Since the correct method is:-

`addLink(pagenum, pagedest, rect, border=None, fit='/Fit', *args)`

Thus I suggest you use the easiest non python method so:-

Open the Drawing in [Sejda (online](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor) or desktop) and select the co-ordinates with a marquee where the hyperlink is needed then type in the URL target or page number and hit save. It is so much easier than starting to program your unknown co-ordinates from inside python and then overcoming thousands of hiccups.

[image]